# Difference in Abstraction and Function overriding?

Tags: java

In java, we give body to an abstract method of parent class inside the child class and then call that function via child class object like:

```
//let the abstract  function be fun  then,     
child c= new child();    
c.fun();
```

then `fun` executes the body given by `child` but what's new in this as same being done in function overriding?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that subclasses that won't also be abstract **must** implement all inherited abstract methods. Also, the concrete implementation can't call `super.method()` as there's no implementation in the abstract class.

As to the why, or perhaps more explicitly, why choose the abstract superclass rather than an interface: often it's useful to provide implementations of only *some* methods of an interface - for instance for code-sharing - and require concrete subclasses to provide specific implementations for other parts of the interface.

Comment: When you implement an abstract method, you aren't overriding anything since there is nothing to override. An overriding method can call `super.sameMethod`, which is obviously not the case here.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik point taken. terminology confusion on my part, answer edited, thanks

Comment: I thank you for your reply but, want to  know What is special in the concept abstraction with respect to function overriding ... when to use it, the work this concept does isn't hiding the information or anything which should be as per its definition ---"Hiding the details"

Answer (score 0):

The abstraction means that the developer has (explicit) to implement the method. Overriding means that the developer implement a method that's already implement. This is by definition of the languaje.